# How to encrypt SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, codenameone

I will like to encrypt the SQLite database that I am using for offline Codenameone App. Any ideas how that can be accomplished in codenameone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the SQLite version that's built into the OS by default to keep the apps small and simple. These versions are usually compiled with encryption turned off. You can get a version with encryption turned on and link it into the app then replace it by following the example we used for Spatialite: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/spatial-pluggable-sqlite.html

See the actual cn1lib for that https://github.com/shannah/cn1-spatialite

I'm guessing that an encryption enabled cn1lib for sqlite would be simpler.

FYI we already support seamless storage encryption using this approach: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/seamless-storage-encryption.html

Comment: Thanks. Will attempt.

Comment: Thanks, i used Spatilite but is still unclear to me how to encrypt my database. where I should add a password to my Db or it is encrypted by default?

Comment: This would require building an encrypted sqlite native cn1lib similar to the one we did for spatialite. I suggest just using storage instead since encryption is built-in.